# How to cancel previous runs in the PR when you push new commits(update the current) in github-actions

Tags: git, github, yaml, github-actions

When I push my commits to a PR my tests are triggered for this commit. After that, if I push additional commits to this PR, tests in Github Actions runs on both commits.

I need to cancel the previous run and run only on the most recent pushed commit.

How can I configure my yaml file to achieve that?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can use [Concurrency](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#concurrency):

> Concurrency ensures that only a single job or workflow using the same concurrency group will run at a time.

```
concurrency: 
  group: ${{ github.head_ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
```

Comment: Works really well. Note: `concurrency` is "currently in beta and subject to change" as of 05/10/2021.

Comment: what level is this at? Every example just shows it all alone... not in a full file or example. Thank you.

Comment: @naspinski Working example https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager/blob/release/3.7/.github/workflows/android-feature.yml

Comment: @EmmanuelMess In your answer you say `github.head_ref` whereas in your repo reference you have just `github.ref` just as in https://github.community/t/stop-running-actions-when-new-commit-pushed-to-branch/16455/5. Which one is better?

Comment: @CsabaToth `github.ref` see [here](https://docs.github.com/es/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context). `head_ref` "is only available when the event that triggers a workflow run is either pull_request or pull_request_target." but `ref` is just "The branch or tag ref that triggered the workflow run."

Answer (score 153):

To cancel a currently running workflow from **the same PR, branch or tag** when a new workflow is triggered you can use:

```yaml
name: Workflow X

on: # ...

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.event.pull_request.number || github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs: # ...
```

**Explanation:**

- `${{ github.workflow }}`: the workflow name is used to generate the concurrency group (e.g. `Workflow 1`). That allows you to have more than one different workflow (eg. `workflow1.yaml` and `workflow2.yaml`) triggered on the same event (e.g. a PR). Otherwise, `workflow1.yaml` would cancel `workflow2.yaml` or viceversa.
- `${{ github.event.pull_request.number`: when the trigger event is a PR, it will use the PR number to generate the concurrency group (e.g. `workflow1-33`).
- `|| github.ref }}`: when the trigger is not a PR but a push, it will use the branch or tag name to generate the concurrency group (e.g. `workflow1-branch1`).
- `cancel-in-progress: true`: if cancel-in-progress is omitted or set to false, when a new workflow is triggered, the currently running workflow won't be cancelled, and the new workflow will be queued pending until the previous one is done.

Ref: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency

Comment: This is a great explanation, especially because adding `${{ github.workflow}}` is important when there are different workflows to consider. 
Since `github.ref` for pull requests it is `refs/pull/<pr_number>/merge` it is also sufficiently unique. It seems that a slightly simpler group is as effective: 
`group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}`
I'm therefore curious why it was necessary for the specific logic to handle `event.pull_request.number` in your answer.

Comment: I would also consider changing `${{ github.ref }}` to `${{ github.ref || github.run_id }}` as mentioned in the GitHub docs on concurrency. This allows for arbitrary events that might not have a ref, such as `workflow_dispatch`, to run the workflow in their own group.
So in summary from both of my comments: `group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref || github.run_id }}`

Answer (score 11):

You will also want to make sure you account for having multiple workflows in the same repository so that you only cancel in-progress runs of the same workflow.

Snippet from the [Using concurrency](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency#example-only-cancel-in-progress-jobs-or-runs-for-the-current-workflow) GitHub docs:

```yaml
concurrency: 
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
```

Full, working example ([Source](https://github.com/philip-gai/philip-gai/blob/main/.github/workflows/cancel-in-progress.yml)):

```
name: CI with in-progress cancellations

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
  workflow_dispatch:

# This is what will cancel the workflow
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Print concurrency group
        run: echo '${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}'
      - name: Sleep 15s
        run: sleep 15s
```

Answer (score 4):

### Update

This is no longer valid, GitHub Actions has improved this experience since. [Check out the alternative answer first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67939898/736079).

### Old answer

Like we had "There's an app for that!", now it's "There's an Action for that!":

```
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Cancel Previous Runs
        uses: styfle/cancel-workflow-action@0.8.0
        with:
          access_token: ${{ github.token }}
      #- name: Run Tests
      #  uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      #  run: node test.js
      # ... etc
```

https://github.com/styfle/cancel-workflow-action

Comment: cancel-workflow-action is deprecated in favor of [concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67939898/3124150).

Comment: @max can you unaccept this answer and move it over to the alternative. Mine is no longer valid as GitHub Actions has grown.

Comment: sure, done, thx