# How to cancel existing runs when a new push happens on GitHub Actions, but only for PRs?

Tags: github-actions

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#concurrency) (there's also a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66336834/253468)), I wrote this:

```yaml
on:
  push
concurrency:
  # Documentation suggests ${{ github.head_ref }}, but that's only available on pull_request/pull_request_target triggers.
  group: ci-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
jobs:
  ...
```

This creates a separate group for each branch, and cancels builds if there's a later push/force push to a branch.
Sadly, this also cancels `master` builds, which I don't want. On `master` all commits should complete running, so it's easy to see when something broke.

I'm essentially looking for a way to say:

```yaml
concurrency:
  group: ci-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
  if: github.ref != 'refs/heads/master'
```

Comment: [_"A concurrency group can be any string or expression"_](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#concurrency) - so maybe on master the group is the commit hash, i.e. nothing gets grouped, whereas off master it's the branch?

Comment: ‍♂️, yes! Thank you! Maybe it's too early in the morning.

Comment: That's fun, @jonrsharpe, there's no ternary here... anyway I found workarounds to get an "if" in there, let me try them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no ternary operator in [GitHub Actions expression syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions), but I found some [workarounds](https://github.community/t/do-expressions-support-ternary-operators-to-change-their-returned-value/18114/3): http://rickluna.com/wp/tag/fake-ternary/ is an awesome post about this.

The commit hash of the head branch is available in the [`github` context object](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context) as `github.sha`.

In my case truthyness in fake ternary is not an issue, it actually always has to have a value, so I can do:

```yaml
concurrency:
  # Documentation suggests ${{ github.head_ref }}, but that's only available on pull_request/pull_request_target triggers, so using ${{ github.ref }}.
  # On master, we want all builds to complete even if merging happens faster to make it easier to discover at which point something broke.
  group: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' && format('ci-master-{0}', github.sha) || format('ci-{0}', github.ref) }}
```

Comment: For getting a real ternary vote here: https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/409

Comment: A note about the `${{ x && <yes> || <false> }}` construct:

This only works if `<yes>` isn't the empty string. If `<yes> == ''` then `''` is considered as `false`, which then evaluates the right hand side of the `||`. Just lost ten minutes over this, hope it helps!

Answer (score 20):

You can specify `cancel-in-progress` based on the default branch:

```yaml
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: ${{ github.ref != 'refs/heads/master' }}
```

Comment: OMG, that's a proper mic-drop there @thisismydesign. Use expression, not a hardcoded Boolean ‍♂️.

Comment: I don't think you even need the ternary hack, since `==` and `!=` is Boolean.

Comment: @TWiStErRob good point!